# youtube video id, pass it to url

Tags: php

I was trying to create a youtube video image for my blog, so that if a user writes a post including his text and a youtube link, my blog will generate a text and an image preview of youtube video (like in facebook when you post a youtube link). This is what I have done:

```
<?php

    $find_youtube = "http://www.youtube.com";

    if(preg_match("[$find_youtube]", $row['comment'])) {

        parse_str( parse_url( $row['comment'], PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );

        $row['comment'] = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i", "</br><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$my_array_of_vars['v']."/default.jpg' title='YouTube Video' alt='YouTube Video' /></br>", $row['comment']);

    }
?>
```

my problem is that I cannot **$my_array_of_vars** to the link. Any idea how to fix this problem...or any other suggestions?

Comment: Try ` if(preg_match("/[$find_youtube]/", $row['comment']))`

Comment: gives me error Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: `$vidz = '/[$find_youtube]/';
if(preg_match($vidz, $row['comment']))`

Comment: Of course you’ll get that warning, because your _delimiter_ `/` is present in the pattern as well, and is not properly escaped. You could use a different delimiter, or escape its occurrence in your specific search string manually – or do it right from the beginning, and use [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) when inserting parts into a search pattern dynamically.

Comment: any idea how to do it please ?